# Printing an overview of local storage items

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to print a nice overview of all localstorage items on my html page. I made the following loop to achieve that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    var entry = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    $('body').append('<article rel="'+entry[0]['key']+'"><h2>'+entry[0]['title']+'</h2><img class="entry_img" src="'+entry[0]['image']+'"><p><span class="actions"><img class="delete" src="img/deleteicon.png" /></span>'+entry[0]['content']+'<span class="time">Toegevoegd op:'+entry.[0]['date']+'</span>'+entry.[0]['location']+'</p></article>');
}
```

Each item in localstorage is a nice array with information in it. It thought this code should print the values. But it gives me a bunch of undefined's. How can I correctly access the values?

An example of an entry when logged:

```
1396267647 => {"title":"Entry 1","image":"http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape_10.jpg","content":"Entry 1","date":"31-03-14","location":"Tilburg","key":1396267647}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is a bunch of string key/value pairs, so `entry` will always be a string.

Therefore, you probably have something like:

```
var entry = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)); // Returns "example"
entry[0] // Returns "e"
entry[0]['key'] // Returns undefined
```

If you need to store *objects* in local storage, you need to stringify them first using something like JSON.stringify.

**From your edit:** Looks like you have a JSON string already, so all you need to do is parse it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))); // Parse the string value
    $('body').append('<article rel="'+entry[0]['key']+'"><h2>'+entry[0]['title']+'</h2><img class="entry_img" src="'+entry[0]['image']+'"><p><span class="actions"><img class="delete" src="img/deleteicon.png" /></span>'+entry[0]['content']+'<span class="time">Toegevoegd op:'+entry.[0]['date']+'</span>'+entry.[0]['location']+'</p></article>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve part of my problem. Now I get this error though: [Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'entry[0]['title']')

Comment: @FrankKluytmans `entry` is an object, not an array. So you can access without the array indexer, e.g. `entry.title`

Comment: Yes indeed. My bad! Thanks for helping me out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have syntax error in your code, look at: `entry.[0]['date']`, it should be `entry[0]['date']` (without the dot).

And the same error is for `entry.[0]['location']`, remove the dot.